# How do I get the correct value for sketchPath in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, processing

I want to setup IntelliJ IDEA to compile Processing sketches. So far I've been following the instructions found here:
http://www.slideshare.net/eskimoblood/processing-in-intellij

These instructions work fine for code completion and basic "drawing". But I run into problems once I want to access files – i.e. an image - inside the data folder which is created on slide 19. First the code of my Processing class:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class IntellijTest extends PApplet
{
    private PImage image;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        size(400, 400);
        println(sketchPath);
        // load image
        image = loadImage("test.png");
    }


    @Override
    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        noStroke();
        fill(200);
        rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
        // draw image
        image(image, 110, 100);
    }
}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin
The file "test.png" is missing or inaccessible, make sure the URL is valid or that the file has been added to your sketch and is readable.
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PGraphics.image(PGraphics.java:3572)
    at processing.core.PApplet.image(PApplet.java:12604)
    at IntellijTest.draw(IntellijTest.java:28)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2306)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:243)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

As you can see the sketchPath is set to "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin". So the running sketch (Applet) does not find the image. IntelliJ does even warn me about it, but I still haven't figured out how to add the image to the sketch or better how to set the correct sketchPath value so that the sketch finds all files inside the data folder at runtime.

I'ld really appreciate any hints or insights on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Where is `test.png` in relation to your Applet?

Comment: The test.png is in the folder 'data' inside the sketch folder. By default Processing looks for file to load in this location – at least when the Applet is compiled with the Processing GUI. If the sketchPath value inside the applet would be something like '/.../mySketch' instead of '/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/bin' the compiled Processing applet would load the image. At least I hope it would...

Comment: Can you provide the file structure of your project? The data folder may no be in the right spot

Comment: Sorry about my late response. I somehow didn't get any notification about the update/comment on my question.

Comment: Here's my project file structure:
**project_folder** /data/test.png & /src/IntellijTest.java

Comment: @J.P.Armstrong Your comment about the file structure made me think and when I move the data folder into the src folder the compiled sketch finds the image. So, the following structure works: **project_folder** /src/IntellijTest.java & /src/data/test.png. But this solution is not very clean. I would rather like to have the data not in the src package. Do you have any other recommendation on how to solve this?

Comment: I normally put config files in `/src/main/resources` and "mark it" as source folder. It should show up in the root of your target/*projectName*

Comment: Great tip! Thank you. I wasn't aware of the fact that non-compilable files inside a folder marked as source folder are copied to the target folder and thereby are available inside the sketch. This approach works for both of the following scenarios: **project** /data/test.png, where the folder _data_ is marked as source folder, and **project** /resources/data/test.png, where the folder _resources_ is marked as source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include files into your target directory without having to include it in your source folder. To accomplish you need to "mark it" the auxiliary folder  as a source folder.

I keep my source files in `/src/main/java` and my resources in `/src/main/resources` where resources contains all my configuration properties and other things that don't belong in the source code. You can right click on the folder in the project explorer and "Mark it" as source. It should appear at the root of your `target/project/`.

Also keep in mind if you're running a Java Application (not Applet), Java will uses the system environment `classpath` to resolve relative paths. So as you start calling files in your program, Java will look in the folders listed in the `classpath` to resolve file locations as well as look in the root of your `target` project.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. I solved it by marking the data directory as Source Root

Comment: This helped me, too. You should put the data directory in the same directory the resources directory for Processing to accept it (unless you have structured your project differently on purpose).